# How can I add computed state to graph objects in React Apollo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I really like the graphQL pattern of having components request their own data, but some data properties are expensive to compute and so I want to localize the logic (and code) to do so.

```
function CheaterList({ data: { PlayerList: players } }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {players && players.map(({ name, isCheater }) => (
        <li key={name}>{name} seems to be a {isCheater ? 'cheater' : 'normal player'}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default graphql(gql`
  query GetList {
    PlayerList {
      name,
      isCheater
    }
  }
`)(CheaterList);
```

The schema looks like:

```
type Queries {
    PlayerList: [Player]
}

type Player {
    name: String,
    kills: Integer,
    deaths: Integer
}
```

And so I want to add the `isCheater` property to Player and have its code be:

```
function computeIsCheater(player: Player){
    // This is a simplified version of what it actually is for the sake of the example
    return player.deaths == 0 || (player.kills / player.deaths) > 20;
}
```

How would I do that?

Another way of phrasing this would be: how do I get the isCheater property to look as though it came from the backend? (However, if an optimistic update were applied the function should rerun on the new data)

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#options-from-props) it looks like you can pass a second argument to ```graphql``` to pass computed properties?

Comment: @Varinder thats how you pass properties to the query which is different than what I'm asking here.

Comment: True, would [Arbitrary Transformation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-props-option) be of any help?

Comment: No, thats the equivalent of computing the property value from within the component itself. I would like each component to only declare that it needs `Player { isCheater }` and then have the data appear, similar to how it would if the data were coming from a remote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note**: Local state management is now baked into `apollo-client` -- there's no need to add a separate link in order to make use of local resolvers and the `@client` directive. For an example of mixing local and remote fields, [check out of the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/#local-data-query-flow). Original answer follows.

As long as you're using Apollo 2.0, this should be possible by utilizing `apollo-link-state` as [outlined in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html#combine).

Modify your client configuration to include `apollo-link-state`:

```
import { withClientState } from 'apollo-link-state';

const stateLink = withClientState({
  cache, //same cache object you pass to the client constructor
  resolvers: linkStateResolvers,
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: ApolloLink.from([stateLink, new HttpLink()]),
});
```

Define your client-only resolvers:

```
const linkStateResolvers = {
  Player: {
    isCheater: (player, args, ctx) => {
      return player.deaths == 0 || (player.kills / player.deaths) > 20
    }
  }
}
```

Use the @client directive in your query

```
export default graphql(gql`
  query GetList {
    PlayerList {
      name
      kills
      deaths
      isCheater @client
    }
  }
`)(CheaterList);
```

However, it appears that combining local and remote fields in a single query is currently broken. There's an open issue [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/issues/140) that you can track.